# Not able to install ejs-lint

Tags: node.js, permissions, ejs

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'catch' in /Users/aishwarya/Desktop/projects/todo-list/views/index.ejs while compiling ejs

If the above error is not helpful, you may want to try EJS-Lint:
https://github.com/RyanZim/EJS-Lint
Or, if you meant to create an async function, pass `async: true` as an option.
at new Function ()
at Template.compile (/Users/aishwarya/Desktop/projects/todo-list/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:673:12)
at Object.compile (/Users/aishwarya/Desktop/projects/todo-list/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:398:16)
at handleCache (/Users/aishwarya/Desktop/projects/todo-list/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:235:18)
at tryHandleCache (/Users/aishwarya/Desktop/projects/todo-list/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:274:16)
at exports.renderFile [as engine] (/Users/aishwarya/Desktop/projects/todo-list/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:491:10)
at View.render (/Users/aishwarya/Desktop/projects/todo-list/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:135:8)
at tryRender (/Users/aishwarya/Desktop/projects/todo-list/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:657:10)
at Function.render (/Users/aishwarya/Desktop/projects/todo-list/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:609:3)
at ServerResponse.render (/Users/aishwarya/Desktop/projects/todo-list/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1039:7)

I tried changing the admin level but still not sure what permission it ios asking for